# Linq query and potential self join/group by

Tags: c#, linq

Suffering sadly from brain fade. I have the following scenario:

```
void Main()
{
    List<CaseBase> caseList = new List<UserQuery.CaseBase>();
    caseList.Add(new CaseBase() {CaseID = 1, CaseSequence = 1, CaseStatus = 1});
    caseList.Add(new CaseBase() {CaseID = 1, CaseSequence = 2, CaseStatus = 2});
    caseList.Add(new CaseBase() {CaseID = 2, CaseSequence = 1, CaseStatus = 1});

    var cases = caseList.Where(x => new List<int> {2}.Contains(x.CaseStatus));
    
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class CaseBase
{ 
    public int CaseID {get;set;}
    public int CaseSequence {get;set;}
    public int CaseStatus {get;set;}
}
```

Which returns the expected

| CaseID | CaseSequence | CaseStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |

What I want are all cases with the same ID where one of them has a status of 2.

| CaseID | CaseSequence | CaseStatus |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |

Which should be simple but I'm struggling for a simple solution.

Comment: That second table shows an item that doesn't even exist in the original list, so your expectation isn't really clear.

Comment: @Plasmadog Thanks, typo, fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to proceed:

1. You can combine the cases by `CaseID` and select the matching groups and then break them apart:

   ```
   var cases = caseList
                   .GroupBy(c => c.CaseID)
                   .Where(cg => cg.Any(c => new List<int> { 2 }.Contains(c.CaseStatus)))
                   .SelectMany(cg => cg);
   ```
2. You can find the desired `CaseID`s and then get all matching cases:

   ```
   var wantedCaseIDs = caseList
                           .Where(c => new List<int> { 2 }.Contains(c.CaseStatus))
                           .Select(c => c.CaseID)
                           .ToHashSet();
   var cases = caseList.Where(c => wantedCaseIDs.Contains(c.CaseID));
   ```

Comment: Thanks, thought it might be something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Or you might want to do it like this:

```
void Main()
{
    List<CaseBase> caseList = new List<UserQuery.CaseBase>();
    caseList.Add(new CaseBase() { CaseID = 1, CaseSequence = 1, CaseStatus = 1 });
    caseList.Add(new CaseBase() { CaseID = 1, CaseSequence = 2, CaseStatus = 2 });
    caseList.Add(new CaseBase() { CaseID = 2, CaseSequence = 1, CaseStatus = 1 });
    
    var cases = caseList.Where(x => new List<int> { 2 }.Contains(x.CaseStatus))
        .Join(caseList,x => x.CaseID,y => y.CaseID,(x,y) => new {x,y})
        .Select(z => z.y)
        .Dump();

}
```